# How can I use an interface to create a simple bridge between two activities?

Tags: java, android, interface, observer-pattern

I am trying to learn how to use interfaces in my android JAVA code. I've created this simple app that wants to show a toast when the button is clicked in the MainActivity, but I want to go via the interface and SecondActivity to achieve this.....But I am not able to get the job done.....Because the interface instance in the SecondActivity is shown to be null by the debugger, when executing its onCreate method.

Obviously, the logic isn't right, but I can't figure out exactly what is wrong.....I'm learning on my own, any help is highly appreciated!

I'm a complete beginner so, please be kind.

Also, I've included all of the code below:

---

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interface {

```
Button myButton;
Intent mainIntent;
SecondActivity myMain2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    myMain2 = new SecondActivity();
    myMain2.setMyInterface(this);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void showOnClick() {
    Toast.makeText(myMain2, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

---

public interface Interface {

```
void showOnClick ();
```

}

---

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Interface myInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    if (myInterface != null) {
        myInterface.showOnClick();
    }
}

public void setMyInterface(Interface myInterface){
    this.myInterface =  myInterface;
}
```

}

---

Thanks in Advance!

EDIT(1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
MyInterface{

Intent intent_mainActivity;
WorkoutListFragment myWorkoutFrag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWorkoutFrag = new WorkoutListFragment();
    myWorkoutFrag.setListener(this);

}

@Override
public void itemClicked(long id) {
    intent_mainActivity = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    intent_mainActivity.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_ID, 
(int)id);
    startActivity(intent_mainActivity);
}

}
```

---

```
public interface MyInterface {
void itemClicked(long id);
}
```

---

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {

public WorkoutListFragment() {}

private MyInterface listener;

public void setListener(MyInterface myInterface){
    this.listener = myInterface;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String [] names = new String[Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
names);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}
//
//    @Override
//    public void onAttach(Context context) {
//        super.onAttach(context);
//        this.listener = (MyInterface)context;
//    }

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View itemView, int 
position, long id){
    if (listener != null){
        listener.itemClicked(id);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just specify what you do wrong.

```
myMain2 = new SecondActivity();
myMain2.setMyInterface(this);
```

```
mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

You set interface for myMain2 but when show activity from a button Android does not show your myMain2, it will be create a new instance of SecondActivity base on your Intent you pass. It means when SecondActivity call onCreate it has no instance of myInterface.

Basically communication between 2 activity should be using startActivityForResult or some special case using Broadcast or event bus pattern

Comment: This helps to understand why "myInterface" instance is null when the second activity is launched, but I still don't know how to fix it.....Could you please elaborate further?
Thanks, though.

Comment: Easy communication, you perform some actions, events in SecondActivity you pass to MainActivity, no need show Toast immediately from MainActivity. try to learn about startActivityForResult when start SecondActivity from the button. In SecondActivity when done don't forget call setResult and finnish(). I already said some special case when you want to pass data immediately you can using BroadCast or Event Bus library

Comment: I know this example for your leaning, if you give me what exactly you want to do I will give you specifically recommend!

Comment: I'll learn the startActivityForResult.......And then try this again......|

But I had one more question relating to this, 

I created a fragment that binds itself to an interface in its onAttach() method, but I don't understand how exactly it works.......here are the lines that I don't get:      

//

public void onAttach(Context context){

this.listener = (Listener)context;

//
       
Listener is the interface
 and listener is the instance of Listener in my fragment.

Comment: Ok let me explain it, you wonder that why fragment can use it with activity and two activities not right?

Comment: Yes, and also what does.......... this.listener = (Listener)context;..............do?

Comment: When show fragment you have to use fragment manager of host Activity, it means every child fragment can associate with activity, you can get reference of host activity by getActivity on fragment or override onAttach. When you get instance of Activity I think you know how to cast it to Interface you already implements

Comment: So what you're saying is that......the context gets a reference of my hostActivity which is implementing the interface and then the cast (Listener) extracts the Interface from the context of the Activity? and assigns the interface of hostActivity to the listener instance?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I know you still not sure about why context pass to onAttach and host activity is same right?

Comment: I know that onAttach is a part of the life cycle of a fragment. The fragment needs to know to which activity it is being attached, so the context is required for the onAttach method to run, and since context variable is already there, we are just using it for our purpose, rather than creating a setter method for the interface instance.

But I don't get one thing, If I use the setter method, the fragment stops responding to any clicks which worked fine when I used the onAttach route.Now, why would that be? Is it the same issue as you described earlier? that the instance of interface is null?

Comment: They won't allow me to post another question, Is there any other way I could reach you?

Comment: update inside this question, I need know how to you set interface for fragment

Comment: Edit (1): I have added the relevant code, just ignore the rest.....Cause this is the portion that is causing problems.

Comment: activity_main you declare WorkoutListFragment?

Comment: I did,,,,,
When I'm using the setter method......
If I use the onAttach( ) route, I don't need it.....But I disable that method to see if the setter method works......And as it turns out, the setter doesn't work.

Comment: myWorkoutFrag = new WorkoutListFragment();
    myWorkoutFrag.setListener(this);

Comment: You still wrong in here, when you set fragment in XML, Android system create fragment instance. to make it work in Activity you should getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(your_fragment_id) and set listener

Comment: Ok, hope that help you understand clearly about Activity and Fragment

Comment: You bet it did!